# Passing multiple elements to php through js

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get multiple form values to get passed from and html form to a php document and be displayed inside a div area so I can easily style it with css. I have it working by just using a standard "GET" method but it does not allow me to style it or keep it on the same page. I have tried using AJAX with a "onsubmit()" for the form but this doesn't output anything.

The form:

```
<form action ="" method="GET">
            <script src="./ads.js"></script>
                <select name="select" id="select">
                    <option value="">Please select a parameter</option>
                    <option value="DateC">Date Created</option>
                    <option value="DateF">Date Finished</option>
                    <option value="LR">Logistics Rep</option>
                    <option value="Picker">Picker</option>
                    <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="text" id="text"/>
                <input type="submit" name="sub" onsubmit="advSearch(document.getElementById('select').value,document.getElementById('text').value)"/>

            </form> 
            <div id="result"></div>
```

The JS:

```
function advSearch(var1, var2){
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ads.php?q="+var1, true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.open("GET", "ads.php?r="+var2, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery for sending the ajax request? It simplifies the whole process. Some devs try to avoid jQuery but I think it's great for ajax requests.

Comment: A from can contain multible inputs. You don't need javascript for that. When submitting the form both params should be in the url `?select=LR&text=abc`

Comment: [Don't bring in jQuery just to do an ajax request...](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using jQuery's `$.ajax` function or JavaScript's native Fetch API (the latter does not support IE). Using `XMLHttpRequest` is only going to make things more challenging for you unless you *really* need to support legacy.

You should also use the `action` parameter in your form if you're trying to send this data to a server for something, since there's no guarantee the user will have JavaScript enabled. That way the form will submit traditionally if JavaScript fails.

```html
<form id="main-form" action="ads.php" method="GET">
  <script src="./ads.js"></script>
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="">Please select a parameter</option>
    <option value="DateC">Date Created</option>
    <option value="DateF">Date Finished</option>
    <option value="LR">Logistics Rep</option>
    <option value="Picker">Picker</option>
    <option value="Engineer">Engineer</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
  <input type="submit" name="sub" />

</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#main-form').addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
  fetch(
    `ads.php?q=${document.querySelector('#select').value}&r=${document.querySelector('#text').value}`,
    { method: 'GET' }
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => document.querySelector('#result').innerText = text);
});
```

Comment: The code outputs the table as the tags with the data instead of as a table. <a href="./advancedSearch.php">&lt-- Back To Search</a><table border='1'><tr><td>Order Number</td><td>Order Type</td><td>Delays</td><td>Log Rep</td><td>Sales Rep</td><td>Picker</td><td>Pick Start Time</td><td>Pick End Time</td><td>Engineer</td><td>Eng Start Time</td><td>End End Time</td><td>QC Start Time</td><td>QC End Time</td></tr><tr><td>SO409456</td><td>Quick</td><td></td><td></td><td>KP</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><table> Any Fix for this?

Comment: @deadlypants9338 If you're getting HTML back instead of text, use `.innerHTML` instead of `.innerText`. My bad.

Comment: My Guy you are awesome, no need to apologize.